# Creating JButtons in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I'm fairly new to Java and I've been having some difficulties with Swing. I'm trying to create a very simple GUI program which should be create a set of buttons but my code doesn't work.

Here's my code;

```
myPanel = new JPanel();

JButton myButton = new JButton("create buttons");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText());
        for(int i = 0; i < val; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("");
            button.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            myPanel.add(button);
        }
    }
});
```

But nothing happens when I click to "create buttons" button. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh panels that are already running with revalidate:

myPanel.revalidate()

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't he pack() too ?

Comment: I suppose he called pack on the JFrame that he's adding the JPanel on.

Comment: `pack` should be used to adjust the size of the component. If it is fixed size there is no need to call `pack`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to invoke the `validate` method on the `myPanel` to get the contents of the GUI to update, after adding a button on the panel. Also consider the use of IDEs(Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ Idea etc...), that's if it's necessary, for GUI building.